# Showing the taskbar in Parallels Coherence mode

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, windows

I just installed Parallels 6 and upon launching it for the first time, it started up in coherence mode and I saw the taskbar overlayed the Mac OS X UI. After a few seconds, though, it disappeared. I tried enabling the relevant settings I found related to this, but I was never able to get the taskbar to appear again.

How can I show the taskbar in Parallel's Coherence mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Switch to Coherence view.
2. Hold <kbd>option</kbd> and click the Parallels button in the Mac OS X system tray.
3. Navigate to View > Show Windows Taskbar.